# How to deal with Legendary tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-legendary-cards

Can you have more than one "Legendary Token"? I don't think so, but I have a creature named [Tolsimir Wolfblood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTolsimir%20Wolfblood%5d) that allow me to tap it to create a 2/2 Legendary Wolf token named Voja.

If you can't have more than one legendary creature on the field, would you have to sacrifice the wolf token or Tolsimir Wolfblood? How does that work?

Are legendary tokens and legendary creatures different from each other? Or is it that legendary creatures can't have the same name as the other?

Comment: Flavorwise, Tolsimir has a wolf companion, and if that wolf dies, Tolsimir can tap to resurrect it. But if the wolf is already on the battlefield, Tolsimir can't create a second one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe you've misinterpreted the "Legend Rule", which is CR 704.5j (emphasis mine):

> 704.5j If a player controls two or more legendary permanents **with the same name**, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners’ graveyards. This is called the “legend rule.”

You can have as many legendary permanents as you want, as long as they have different names. Some cards, like [Brothers Yamazaki](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrothers%20Yamazaki%5d) and [Mirror Gallery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirror%20Gallery%5d) can ignore that rule.

Also, you can read Tolsimir Wolfblood's rulings in its gatherer page:

> **7/1/2013:** The “legend rule” means that creating a second Voja while one is already under your control will result in one of them being put into its owner’s graveyard (where it promptly ceases to exist). You choose which of the two remains on the battlefield and which is put into the graveyard.

In your specific case, you can only have *one* Voja token, and only *one* [Tolsimir Wolfblood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTolsimir%20Wolfblood%5d), but both permanents can coexist on the battlefield.

Answer (score 4):

[Tolsimir Wolfblood](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tolsimir%20Wolfblood)'s ability reads:

> [image: {T}]: Create a legendary 2/2 green and white Wolf creature token named Voja.

The rule for the legendary supertype reads:

> 704.5j If a player controls two or more legendary permanents with the same name, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners’ graveyards. This is called the “legend rule.”

Note that the rule specifies they have to have the same name. If you use Tolsimir's ability, you will have two legendary creatures, one named Tolsmir Wolfblood and one named Voja. Since they have different names, they both stay on the battlefield. If you use Tolsimir's ability again to create a second Voja token, you have to destroy either the new token or the old one, since you will have two Voja on the battlefield at the same time.

Three magic cards have modified this rule:

- [Brothers Yamazaki](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brothers%20Yamazaki) do so because they are identical twin brothers, so you can have one, or both of the brothers out at the same time. They specifically ignore this rule when there are two of them exactly in play. This was not changed when the legend rule was adjusted to allow one copy per player, so if two players each have one out and one of those players plays a second one (third total) that player will have to sacrifice one until they are following the current legend rule.
- [Mirror Gallery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirror%20Gallery) simply removes the legend rule from the game while it's in play, allowing unlimited copies of legendary permanents in play. If Mirror Gallery leaves play it immediately applies again and any duplicate legendaries need to be sent to the graveyard.
- [Sakashima of a Thousand Faces](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sakashima%20of%20a%20Thousand%20Faces) works exactly like Mirror Gallery does, except it only applies to you, not to the entire game. Just like Mirror Gallery you can have as many copies of the same legendary permanents in play as long as Sakashima is in play, but the rule applies as soon as Sakashima leaves the battlefield.

Comment: I have four of the Tolsimir Wolfblood's They are awesome creatures if you can get them out lol.  My friends when we play always target me so i never get a chance to play them so I get very sad very very sad.

Comment: @DylanParris take a look at [Wren's Run Packmaster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=140194) I like this one for making powerful wolves